# Highlight div on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to hightlight a div after I dropped an element into it. 
How can I identify the div where I dragged the item to and highlight it?

In my program the code below works but not in this sniplet. Here I cannot drag the div's although I made them draggable. What did I do wrong?

```js
var overviewJS = new function() {
  this.allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
  this.drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }
  this.drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    //$('.tbProject').append("Some content");
    $('.tbProject').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
  }
}
```

```css
.tbDocument {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #412418;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 120px;
}
.tbProject {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #412418;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
[draggable] {
  cursor: move;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #666;
  border: 2px dashed #eee;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
  <center>test</center>
</div>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
  <center>test</center>
</div>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
  <center>test</center>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="tbDocument" draggable="true">
  document to drag
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your namespace syntax is wrong and you did not include jQuery UI which is needed for `.effect()`. To then specifically highlight the drop target use `ev.target`.

Here your adjusted snippet:

```js
overviewJS = {
    allowDrop: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    },
    drag: function (ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    },
    drop: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        //$('.tbProject').append("Some content");
        $(ev.target).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
    }
}
```

```css
.tbDocument {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid #412418;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 120px;
}
.tbProject {
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #412418;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
[draggable] {
    cursor: move;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 2px dashed #eee;
    margin: 10px 0;
    color: white;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-user-drag: element;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
    <center>test</center>
</div>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
    <center>test</center>
</div>
<div class="tbProject" ondrop="overviewJS.drop(event)" ondragover="overviewJS.allowDrop(event)">
    <center>test</center>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="tbDocument" draggable="true">document to drag</div>
```